# Ruby regex expression for floating point numbers

Tags: ruby, regex

I am having trouble constructing a floating point number in ruby.

The number can be either be negative or positive.

And can be something like: 0.00000020402 (**it must have a exactly 1 zero before the decimal if the number is less than one.** )

0.5 would be the correct way but not .5

This is the only rule, otherwise, anything else is fine like below:

-0.4224 (negative) or -0.00002 (negative) or 5.2525

So could some one help me with what is the regular expression that covers these cases for floating point numbers?

This is what I have so far: **^[+-]?(?:(?!0)\d{1,2}|0)(?:.[05])?$**

Comment: Where is your example, or what you've attempted?

Comment: What's the specific issue?

Comment: ^[+-]?(?:(?!0)\d{1,2}|0)(?:\.[05])?$

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**Better:**

```
(^[+-]?(?:0|[1-9]\d*)(?:\.(?:\d*[1-9]|0))?)$
```

http://regex101.com/r/mO1gW8

<s>I'd say this should work quite well for you:</s>

http://regex101.com/r/oT2nF7

**Matches:**

```
0.00000020402
0.0056
+0.5
-1
1.5
0.3565465
11.666654654
10.0
```

**Doesn't match:**

```
0.00560
.55555654654
11.
00000.66
10.00
10.a
0.4a
```

Comment: Thank you all for your answers

Comment: this won't match `10.0` for example

Comment: @pguardiario you're right, see update. Much improved.

Comment: This is incorrect. Among other problems, it matches `0.4a` or even `0.4@`.

Comment: @EdCottrell OK, seriously, that's uncool! Let me fix.

Comment: @EdCottrell fixed, I took the lazy way out with that `[^0]`.

Comment: Much better. You could still remove the first two `$`, though -- they don't do anything.

Comment: @EdCottrell yes, quite true. Tis what I get for writing code in an airport...

Answer (score 6):

If you just want to match a floating point number, you can do this:

```
^[+-]?([1-9]\d*|0)(\.\d+)?$
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/13Xxil9sWpQZNNqG)

Examples:

- `0.5` **Matches**
- `.5` **not a match**
- `00.5` **not a match**
- `123.0` **Matches**
- `+1123` **Matches**
- `-0.4` **Matches**
- `0.` **not a match**
- `-.4` **not a match**
- `+0.54` **Matches**

Edit: if you want to exclude `-0` as a match, use this:

```
^(?!-0$)[+-]?([1-9]\d*|0)(\.\d+)?$
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/4DccgyBG9RlTqqwu)

Comment: +1 This looks good to me, other than matching `-0` (which is probably not worth worrying about)

Comment: @pguardiario Thanks for pointing that out; I added an alternate version in case OP cares about this.

Answer (score 0):

This should work for floating point numbers:

```
\A[+-]?(\d\.\d+)?\Z
```

example: http://regex101.com/r/sX2cT7

ruby:

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby -w

def is_a_number?(s)

  s.to_s.match(/\A[+-]?(\d\.\d+)?\Z/) == nil ? false : true

end

puts is_a_number?("+0.00000020402")
puts is_a_number?("-0.00000020402")
```

Answer (score -2):

try this : `^[-+]?(\d+[.])?\d+$` .

Comment: I think he wants to return more than `0.`

Comment: This matches `abc-5.4zyer` and a lot of other invalid strings.

Comment: no not match. \d means numbers only !!!

Comment: l'L'l, I just added ^ at the beginning and $ at the end of reg exp so your problem is resolved.